# Build tensorflow dataset of images from path list

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a tensorflow dataset based on a file which contains a list of images but, even though I tried many variations of my code I always get the same error.

The first thing I do is load a pandas dataframe
`df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')`
The file is something like:

```
filename,mynumber
/path/to/image1.png,100
/path/to/image2.png,200
/path/to/image2.png,300
[...]
```

The next thing I'm trying to do is add a new column called "image_data" using a function to load image data like this:

```
def load_image(file_name):
  raw = tf.io.read_file(file_name)
  tensor = tf.io.decode_image(raw)
  tensor = tf.cast(tensor, tf.float32)
  return tensor

df['bytes'] = df['filename'].apply(lambda f: load_image(f))
```

For clarity I assign the newly created column to X and the label column to Y:

```
X = df['bytes']
Y = df['mynumber']
```

I define a simple Sequential model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255,input_shape=(1264, 1984, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

In the end, after calling the compile method, I try to call fit likethis:

```
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=5, batch_size=12, verbose=1)
```

Then I receive the following error

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).
```

I tried many variations of my code with no luck.
I suppose I'm loading the image data in a wrong way.
What am I missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to fit your model with a column of tf.Tensors which is not supported. To feed data to your model, you need to create a TensorFlow dataset. Here's one way to do it:

```
def load_image(file_name):
  raw = tf.io.read_file(file_name)
  tensor = tf.io.decode_image(raw)
  tensor = tf.cast(tensor, tf.float32) / 255.0
  return tensor

def create_dataset(file_names, labels):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_names, labels))
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda file_name, label: (load_image(file_name), label))
  return dataset

file_names = df['filename'].to_numpy()
labels = df['mynumber'].to_numpy()
dataset = create_dataset(file_names, labels)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.backend.resize_images(x, (1264, 1984), "channels_last"), input_shape=(None, None, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(dataset.batch(12), epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

Note that, instead of using the Rescaling layer, a Lambda layer with a resize_images function is used to resize the images, and the images are normalized by dividing by 255.0 in the load_image function.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but I receive the following error when I instantiate the model:

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_1" (type Lambda).

Missing required positional argument

Call arguments received by layer "lambda_1" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None

Comment: model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1264, 1984, 1), input_shape=(1264, 1984, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

Comment: This layer works only if I use the same shape (1264, 1984, 1), otherwise I get an error. I suppose though that this way it has no meaning...

Comment: How to do this for multi-output model?